# How to parse google search result the numbers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a request to Google Search
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=book")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
phrase_extract = soup.find_all(id="result-stats")
print(phrase_extract)
```

The output is

```
[]
```

I checked the web source directly on Chrome browser, I can see this:

```
<div id="result-stats">About 13,120,000,000 results<nobr> (0.51 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

However, if I print the `response.text`, I can't find this string.

**Update:**
This code will work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a request to Google Search
response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=book", 
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.59'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
phrase_extract = soup.find_all(id="result-stats")
print(phrase_extract)
```

The only difference is the `headers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your `soup` to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

---

To simulate human behavior, add a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and a consent `cookie` to your requests `headers`. It also should be fine to use `find()` or `select_one()` instead of `find_all()`, because there is only one element with that `id` holding the information.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            'https://www.google.com/search?q=book',
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.59'}, 
            cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'}).text
        )
phrase_extract = soup.find(id="result-stats")
print(phrase_extract)
```

To get only the numeric results:

```
''.join(e for e in soup.find(id="result-stats").next if e.isnumeric())
```

or

```
''.join(e for e in soup.select_one('#result-stats').next if e.isnumeric())
```

Comment: I found if there is no "headers = xxxx", the error would be the same.